# PHPとImageMagickで画像縦横比が2対3となるよう縮小トリミングしたい

Tags: php, imagemagick

- 画像縦横比が2対3の場合
  何もしない
- 画像縦横比が2対3以外の場合
  画像縦横比が2対3となるよう(良い感じに)縮小したい
  短辺を基準？にしてリサイズ後、(左上基準で)トリミング？？

---

作成中のコード

```
$im = new Imagick();
$size = $im->getImageGeometry();
$w = $size['width'];
$h = $size['height'];

if($w > $h){ //縦が短辺
  if($w*3 != $h*2){
    $im->resize(null, $h, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });
    $im->cropImage(?, $h, 0, 0);
  }

}elseif($w = $h){


}elseif($w < $h){
  if($h*3 != $w*2){
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どの部分がわからないで質問されているのか曖昧な部分がありますが、2:3(縦長)で入力画像のはみでる部分だけをトリミングする場合こんなかんじでしょうか。(小数点以下の端数が出るアス比は適当に近い数字で)

```php
<?php

function crop(string $in, string $out)
{
    $image = new Imagick($in);

    $size = $image->getImageGeometry();
    $w = $size['width'];
    $h = $size['height'];

    if ($w * 1.5 > $h) {
        $width = round($h / 1.5);
        $x = round(($w - $width) / 2);

        $image->cropImage($width, $h, $x, 0);
    } else {
        $height = round($w * 1.5);
        $y = round(($h - $height) / 2);

        $image->cropImage($w, $height, 0, $y);
    }

    $image->writeImage($out);
    $image->clear();
}

// test
crop('https://dummyimage.com/300x600.png', 'out/300x600.png');
crop('https://dummyimage.com/400x600.png', 'out/400x600.png');
crop('https://dummyimage.com/600x300.png', 'out/600x300.png');
crop('https://dummyimage.com/600x400.png', 'out/600x400.png');
crop('https://dummyimage.com/600x600.png', 'out/600x600.png');
crop('https://dummyimage.com/600x800.png', 'out/600x800.png');
crop('https://dummyimage.com/600x1000.png', 'out/600x1000.png');
crop('https://dummyimage.com/900x600.png', 'out/900x600.png');
crop('https://dummyimage.com/1200x600.png', 'out/1200x600.png');
```

`Imagick::cropThumbnailImage`使うのもあり？その場合

```
    if ($w * 1.5 > $h) {
        $width = round($h / 1.5);
        $image->cropThumbnailImage($width, $h);
    } else {
        $height = round($w * 1.5);
        $image->cropThumbnailImage($w, $height);
    }
```

のようにImageMagick側に一部を任せられそうです。

Comment: 期待通り動作しました。1点だけ疑問があるのですが、roundを使用している意図は何ですか？ 処理速度を(少しでも)速くするため？ それともなるべく端数を出さないようにするため？ あるいはそれ以外？？

Comment: 一応誤差を減らすためroundにしておきました(といってもガバガバなのでちゃんとやるならやる場所がちがうといえばそう)。確かにPHPなので少数のままでも自動でキャストはされるので大方問題なく動作はするはずですね。

Comment: なるほど。自動で型をキャストしない言語の場合は、という書き方なのですね